How to implement iOS 18 AI/Siri animation using UIKit

I want to implement the this effect in my app (A colorful wave around screen) using UIKit.
Maybe called ColorfulWaveView and I can add it to UIWindow so that my app can use this effect.
I tried many ways like CAShapeLayer or CAGradientLayer, but seems not very easy to do.... Any idea for this?
